# how secure Parse IAP are compared to StoreKit

Tags: ios, parse-platform, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am developing an app with in-app purchase. I heard people talking about Parse. Can someone provide some information how much of the security do Parse offer compared to normal StoreKit IAP without receipt validation and without using a server? The receipt validation and servers are topics I don't understand and because of that I tend to use some sort of IAP without it. Any information is appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using the Parse Stripe module for IAP? Stripe has security certifications for pretty much anything you could ever want

Comment: I did a research. Somesay say that it is incomplete, not sure in what way

Comment: What is the purchase? Parse already does receipt verification in some cases...

Comment: just no ads function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse verifies receipts for file downloads where the purchased file to download is hosted with parse, but not for 'simple' IAP purchases (which yours is).

Technically there is nothing stopping you from adding a small basically empty file which is downloaded after the purchase so that the verification is run and then you enable your features if you can download the file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with Parse, but I've worked with TapJoy framework, which provides IAP functionality as well. I know that's not exactly your question, but I thought to provide the alternative if Parse didn't work for you.

Comment: @krompir2 I agree, and yrw. Whilst we're on the subject, I looked up a few more ad networks that do rewards, and the newest ones I have tried are inMobi and NativeX. I really like the NativeX approach, super easy to implement and very clear too. And something I really liked about them was that their resource usage is much lower than other ones I came across.